# Serving static content

Tags: servlets, web, static-files

I want to serve static content with a Java Servlet, but is it the best solition? Should I change the static content with file operations or keep files in database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to to use static files on the webserver document root. Storing and fetching from the database is not recommended for performance reasons if the files are indeed going to be static.

Comment: I'll try to run it on a cloud server. So it looks like it is going to cost me working time. I'm currently storing files in database, and they are constantly changing.